# SSRS shows blank page for 1 user

Tags: sonicwall, ssrs

We have a ssrs portal for our clients. they use sonicwall to gain access to our network.

I have one external client/user that can access the vpn, but when he tries to hit the server he gets the spinning circle.

He notes the tab title is 'Reporting Services Web Portal'.  If I go to the portal home page and hit F5, i note i get that title for just a second and then see'Home - SQL Server Reporting Services'
This tells me he is hitting the webserver. The webserver is using port 80.

The DB does happen to be on the same machine, so there is no need for him to have port 1433,1434 open.   He is going to have his IT people try this just to rule it out.

I can not find any mention of any other port necessary. I dont think it is a port issue.

He is not getting challenged at the webserver level so its not a credential issue.

I can log on as him and things work fine, so I am led to believe its not something with his windows account on our server.

He is the only one having troubles. I did ask him to download team viewer and his teamviewer wont let him connect. He cant look at my pc and I cant look at his. I feel like this is a clue.  To me it points to a firewall blocking ports.
(It also makes trouble shooting that much harder).

User reports this worked a week ago. He is talking to his IT guys, but they dont remember changing anything.  :-).

I am baffled. Can anyone suggest a log i could check? Has anyone seen something like this?

Comment: Hi, can you test with his server login ? as you tested with his vpn login, but your account. My feeling is a firewall on is side, but lets test

Comment: i can log into ssrs w/ his credentials. so its not a password or security issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As his logging work on your side, as stated in comment, the next step would do to make a packet monitor from the sonicwall to identify what port the customer block, so he could contact his support to make them open them.

As you can't connect to his computer, ask him to connect, check the VPN IP the client got, and make a display filter with that into the packet monitor.

Add th IP in the source filter, and select the sonicwall option to match the destination filter too, it will allow you to see both side of the communication.

When the filter is done, ask your customer to hit the website.

From there you will see the communication, and you will be able to spot resend and/or dropped packet.

100% Resend on some packet type would mean the remote computer dropped the packet and the appliance retry to send the data. Some random resend would mean he's under a really bad internet connection and might have issue on his side with his internet.

Dropped packet, in red into your log, would mean the appliance dropped it for a missing allow rule in your Firewall's rules, or maybe dropped because of the Gateway Antivirus/App control if you use it. The detail will be in the dropped packet for the real reason.

So as you can see it will lead you to either email their IT's team, if the computer can't receive on certain port, which you will have the log to collaborate.

or it will lead to a rule change from your side, as maybe an app rule kicked in, if you did a firmware update in example.

Comment: excellent suggestions. Ill mark this as the answer

Answer (score 0):

You tried the usual clear browser cache/stored files and shift + f5?  Any chance he has tried on a different browser?

Comment: Teamviewer wont work. another sign (to me) that his firewall is causing some issues.  he has tried multiple browsers. i have not got in and done all the easy stuff...so no.

Comment: Yea in that case I'd have his IT folks check their firewall logs and see if they can see it being blocked.